# Add fields to feeds importer

Tags: 7, files, feeds, importing-exporting

I want to import the fields "alt", "title" and the custom field "copyright_notice" via feeds using the following code:

```
function budg_eu_projects_feeds_processor_targets_alter(&$targets, $entity_type, $bundle_name) {
  foreach (field_info_instances($entity_type, $bundle_name) as $name => $instance) {

    $info = field_info_field($name);

    if ($info['type'] == 'file') {
      $targets[$name . ':alt'] = array(
        'name' => t('@label: Alt', array('@label' => $instance['label'])),
        'callback' => 'budg_eu_projects_set_target',
        'description' => t('The alt tag of the @label field.', array('@label' => $instance['label'])),
        'real_target' => $name,
      );
      $targets[$name . ':title'] = array(
        'name' => t('@label: Title', array('@label' => $instance['label'])),
        'callback' => 'budg_eu_projects_set_target',
        'description' => t('The title of the @label field.', array('@label' => $instance['label'])),
        'real_target' => $name,
      );
      $targets[$name . ':copyright_notice'] = array(
        'name' => t('@label: Copyright Notice', array('@label' => $instance['label'])),
        'callback' => 'budg_eu_projects_set_target',
        'description' => t('The title of the @label field.', array('@label' => $instance['label'])),
        'real_target' => $name,
      );
    }
  }

  return $targets;
}
```

As a callback function I use

```
/**
 * Callback for mapping file fields.
 */
function budg_eu_projects_set_target(FeedsSource $source, $entity, $target, array $values) {

  list($field_name, $sub_field) = explode(':', $target . ':uri');
  $info = field_info_field($field_name);

  // Populate entity.
  $field = isset($entity->$field_name) ? $entity->$field_name : array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array());
  $delta = 0;

  foreach ($values as $v) {
    if ($info['cardinality'] == $delta) {
      break;
    }

    if (!isset($field[LANGUAGE_NONE][$delta])) {
      $field[LANGUAGE_NONE][$delta] = array();
    }

    $field[LANGUAGE_NONE][$delta][$sub_field] = $v;

    $delta++;
  }

  $entity->$field_name = $field;
}
```

I managed to add the fields as a mapping target but the data of the fields are not saved. What is missing?

Thanks
Rainer

Comment: what type of file is it? xml? CSV? or,,,

Comment: It is a csv file

Comment: Looks like you iterate `$values` but don't use the value to set anything. Maybe adding `$field[LANGUAGE_NONE][$delta][$sub_field] = $v;` before `$delta++;` would help?

Comment: Right, of course, but even when adding it, still no results. I updated the above code.

Comment: @abelass if you put someone's handle in your comment they get a little notification. How have you added these fields? IIUC the approach you're using will only work if you've altered the field schema to add those fields. A simpler approach might be to use [fieldable files](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity).

Comment: @Andy, I use Media which requires file entity, I actually take the code from feeds /mappers/file.inc. The fields alt  and title are  fields of the Image file type; copyright_notice is a custom field of the same file type.

Comment: The core code only works because the image field schema includes the fields `title` and `alt`. If you want to use the same with a file field you'll need to alter the file field schema. So at the moment IIUC you're successfully reading the source data from the CSV file and adding it to the entity - but nothing is set up to save (or later load) that data. If your data model permits storing `title` and `alt` with the file entity rather than the file field, I'd still suggest fieldable files. (Which btw is compatible with Media - it actually originated as a Media submodule.)

Comment: I'm re-reading my last comment and actually I shouldn't be advising one way or another really - I think it should just be about your data model. If you need to store the `title` and `alt` per field then it makes sense to either alter the field's schema, or create a new field based on the file field (just the way that image field does). If you want to store those fields per entity, then fieldable files is a more sensible direction.

Comment: @Andy, thanks for your efforts. I have to admit that I am bit lost. *title* and *alt* are provide by the media module, only *copyright_notice* is custom. For each field a table exists in the db i.e *field_data_field_file_image_alt_text*.  I guess the data model I use is the one from the media model + the custom field. What do I have to do concretely to save the data?

Comment: `title` and `alt` are provided by core `image_field` (see [`image_field_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.install/function/image_field_schema/7)) whereas your feeds code works on a `file_field`. I'll try to expand on this a bit in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT the code you've posted *will* populate the entity with the values from the CSV file - but nothing's set up to persist those values. The Field API itself can persist values it knows about. Look at [`file_field_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21file%21file.install/function/file_field_schema/7)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_schema().
 */
function file_field_schema($field) {
  return array(
    'columns' => array(
      'fid' => array(
        'description' => 'The {file_managed}.fid being referenced in this field.',
        ...
      ),
      'display' => array(
        'description' => 'Flag to control whether this file should be displayed when viewing content.',
        ...
      ),
      'description' => array(
        'description' => 'A description of the file.',
        ...
      ),
    ),
    ...
  );
}
```

Through this, the Field API knows to store the file ID, whether or not to show the file when viewing content, and a description of the file. Image field is very close to file field, and shares mostly the same code. And looking at [`image_field_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.install/function/image_field_schema/7) you can see where the title and alt fields come from.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_schema().
 */
function image_field_schema($field) {
  return array(
    'columns' => array(
      'fid' => array(
        'description' => 'The {file_managed}.fid being referenced in this field.',
        ...
      ),
      'alt' => array(
        'description' => "Alternative image text, for the image's 'alt' attribute.",
        ...
      ),
      'title' => array(
        'description' => "Image title text, for the image's 'title' attribute.",
        ...
      ),
      'width' => array(
        'description' => 'The width of the image in pixels.',
        ...
      ),
      'height' => array(
        'description' => 'The height of the image in pixels.',
        ...
      ),
    ),
    ...
  );
}
```

I think the right way forwards depends on your data model. In the example below there are two nodes with file fields, each referring to the same file. Note that they can have different `alt` and `title` fields even though they're referring to the same file.

```
Node 1:
  file_field:
    fid: 1
    alt: A beautiful beach
    title: Wish you were here?

Node 2:
  file_field:
    fid: 1
    alt: Great swimming
    title: Fun for all the family
```

The alternative I suggested in a comment was to add the fields to the entity itself.

```
File 1:
  alt: A beautiful beach
  title: Wish you were here?

Node 1:
  file_field:
    fid: 1

Node 2:
  file_field:
    fid: 1
```

This means the `alt` and `title` will always be the same for a given file. It's obviously for you to decide which model meets your needs more appropriately. If you want to store the data per-field (the first example) you have two choices:

1. Use an existing field and alter its schema with [`hook_schema_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7) - a bit painful as there's no `hook_field_schema_alter()`. **Only do this if conceptually *every* instance of this field should have that extra data.**
2. (I'd prefer this personally) Create a new field that stores the extra columns you're interested in. Image field is the perfect place to look for inspiration, because its functionality's based on file field and it has extra columns.

If you want to store the data per file entity, then you can use fieldable files and I'm fairly sure you should be able to set everything up through the feeds UI. (IE no need for the feeds code above.)

Comment: Actually I use the `Media browser` widget that stores the`title`, `alt` and `copyright_notice` in the tables `field_data_field_file_image_title_text, field_data_field_file_image_alt_text and field_data_field_copyright_notice`, and not in `field_data_field_image` which occurs when the widget `file` is chosen. The first 2 fields are core `media` fields and the third one is a custom field to the `file type` `image`. So there is no need to create the fields, only how to get them saved. How can I make understand feeds that those information have to be attached to the freshley created image?

Comment: @abelass if I understand you correctly then it sounds like you're already using fieldable files (could you confirm?) and you've attached an extra field to the `image` bundle of the `file` entity type. To import a file with fields you'd want a Feeds file processor, but it looks like [Feeds doesn't yet have one built in (patch)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1430190). I'd suggest trying the patch or [files feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_files).

Comment: yes indeed. What I am aiming is a node importer that contains the above mentioned fields. So when importing the nodes the images will be attached to the node and inserted with ther respectif `alt`, `title` and `copyright_notice` values

Comment: @abelass I'm not sure there's anything I can add to my answer and comments.

Comment: thanks for you support. What I need is a mix between the current feeds core function of file import and file_feeds